# converting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' when converting s3 Parquet Dataset to pandas using pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet, pyarrow

I need to read in parquet filed from s3 and filter some columns on it, then upload it back onto s3.
so i have this code that takes the data from `s3 bucket` in `parquet dataset` and then reads it into a `table`
I have been trying to convert this table into `pandas` data frame so i can run queries on it.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import s3fs
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

def src_data_parquet(bucket uri) -> None:
    
    dataset = pq.ParquetDataset(s3_bucket_uri, filesystem=fs)
    #df = dataset.read_pandas().to_pandas()
    table = dataset.read()
    print(table)

    df = table.to_pandas() #This line is throwing an error
```

`index_columns_set = frozenset(index_columns) converting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`
I've done some research on what could have caused this issue and it seems like the problem is that the `table` have some objects in its column values:

```
dstatuschangeddate: timestamp[us]
sgroupid: string
metadata
--------
OrderedDict([(b'pandas',
              b'{"index_columns": [{"kind": "range", "name": null, "start": '
              b'0, "stop": 323328, "step": 1}], "column_indexes": [{"name": '
              b'null, "field_name": null, "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_t'
              b'ype": "object", "metadata": {"encoding": "UTF-8"}}], "column'
              b's": [{"name": "dstatuschangeddate", "field_name": "dstatusch'
              b'angeddate", "pandas_type": "datetime", "numpy_type": "dateti'
              b'me64[ns]", "metadata": null}, {"name": "sgroupid", "field_na'
              b'me": "sgroupid", "pandas_type": "unicode", "numpy_type": "ob'
              b'ject", "metadata": null}], "creator": {"library": "pyarrow",'
              b' "version": "4.0.1"}, "pandas_version": "1.2.4"}'),
             (b'ARROW:schema',
              b'/////0ADAAAQAAAAAAAKAA4ABgAFAAgACgAAAAABBAAQAAAAAAAKAAwAAAAE'
              b'AAgACgAAAIQCAAAEAAAAAQAAAAwAAAAIAAwABAAIAAgAAAAIAAAAEAAAAAYA'
               ......
```

Notes: This file contain timestamps and different Ids associated with those timestamps. I want to get the Max timestamp for each ID.
I could be wrong but I am not sure if using `ParquetDataset` will give me the ability to do that. I tried to use multiple other options example `df = pq.read_table(s3_bucket_uri)` but they all just gave me this error `OSError: Passed non-file path`. So feel free to suggest alternatives. what will be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: It could be that your metadata was generated with an older version of arrow/parquet.  Can you try with `to_pandas(ignore_metadata=True)`?

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I am using pyarrow/parquet for the first time, can you please explain what is it doing? Are there any consequences to using this?

Comment: Actually what version of pandas and pyarrow are you using? (`pyarrow.__version__` and `pandas.__version__`)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading data that has been saved with a different version of parquet/arrow (in your case the data has been saved with a newer version).

The data is backward compatible, but it looks like the metadata isn't, so using `to_pandas(ignore_metadata=True)` should work.

Broadly speaking, Pandas has got a notion of index. But Arrow and Parquet don't support index. So when saving a pandas DataFrame with an index, arrow will add an entry to the metadata to say which column is the index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [1,2,3],
        "col2": ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
)
df_with_index = df.set_index('col1')
pa.Table.from_pandas(df_with_index).schema.metadata
```

```
{'index_columns': ['col1'],
 'column_indexes': [{'name': None,
   'field_name': None,
   'pandas_type': 'unicode',
   'numpy_type': 'object',
   'metadata': {'encoding': 'UTF-8'}}],
 'columns': [{'name': 'col2',
   'field_name': 'col2',
   'pandas_type': 'unicode',
   'numpy_type': 'object',
   'metadata': None},
  {'name': 'col1',
   'field_name': 'col1',
   'pandas_type': 'int64',
   'numpy_type': 'int64',
   'metadata': None}],
 'creator': {'library': 'pyarrow', 'version': '4.0.1'},
 'pandas_version': '1.2.4'}
```

Or in your case to say that the index is just a range (0, 1, 2, 3 ...)

```
{'index_columns': [{'kind': 'range',
   'name': None,
   'start': 0,
   'stop': 323328,
   'step': 1}],
 'column_indexes': [{'name': None,
   'field_name': None,
   'pandas_type': 'unicode',
   'numpy_type': 'object',
   'metadata': {'encoding': 'UTF-8'}}],
 'columns': [{'name': 'dstatuschangeddate',
   'field_name': 'dstatuschangeddate',
   'pandas_type': 'datetime',
   'numpy_type': 'datetime64[ns]',
   'metadata': None},
  {'name': 'sgroupid',
   'field_name': 'sgroupid',
   'pandas_type': 'unicode',
   'numpy_type': 'object',
   'metadata': None}],
 'creator': {'library': 'pyarrow', 'version': '4.0.1'},
 'pandas_version': '1.2.4'}
```

It's possible that your version of arrow isn't compatible with the new metadata syntax. So then arrow is not able to handle the index. Because in your case the index is just a range, it's OK to drop it though, you won't be losing information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Using `to_pandas(ignore_metadata=True)` solved the problem.